# Sort select box items in a JSP scriptlet

Tags: java, jsp, sorting

I'm working on a legacy Tomcat server that is no longer supported by the software developer that provided it.  web.xml doesn't tell me what version of JSP I'm working with, but all the .class files are Java 1.5.

I have a customer who is upset, because the system has html  boxes that are auto-populated by Java, and it fills it straight the the (unordered) results of an XML database query.  I'm trying to sneak a bit of code into the JSP for the Selector to sort the list of fields before they are populated, but it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

The (abridged) relevant code:

```
<%@ page import="src.explorer.ObjectStateFactory"%>
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/c.tld" prefix="c" %>


<jsp:useBean id="ExplorerViewContext" scope="session" type="src.explorer.ExplorerViewContext"/>

...

<c:forEach var="nc" items="${ExplorerViewContext.networkControllers}">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${nc.name == ExplorerViewContext.networkControllerSelection.name}">
            <option value="<c:out value="${selectAction}${nc.objectKey}"/>" selected><c:out value="${nc.name}"/></option>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <option value="<c:out value="${selectAction}${nc.objectKey}"/>"><c:out value="${nc.name}"/></option>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>    
        </select>
```

The relevant code with my additions:

```
 <%@ page import="src.explorer.ObjectStateFactory"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
    <%@ page language="java" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/c.tld" prefix="c" %>


    <jsp:useBean id="ExplorerViewContext" scope="session" type="src.explorer.ExplorerViewContext"/>

    ...

   <%
    final Comparator<src.explorer.XmldbObjectState> NC_ORDER = new Comparator<src.explorer.XmldbObjectState>(){
        public int compare(src.explorer.XmldbObjectState  nc1, src.explorer.XmldbObjectState nc2){
            return nc1.getName().compareTo(nc2.getName());
        }
    };

    List myList = ExplorerViewContext.getNetworkControllers();
    java.util.Collections.sort(myList,NC_ORDER);
    %>
    <c:forEach var="nc" items="${myList}">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${nc.name == ExplorerViewContext.networkControllerSelection.name}">
                <option value="<c:out value="${selectAction}${nc.objectKey}"/>" selected><c:out value="${nc.name}"/></option>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <option value="<c:out value="${selectAction}${nc.objectKey}"/>"><c:out value="${nc.name}"/></option>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>    
            </select>
```

Basically, I'm trying to grab the list and sort it before it gets sent to the HTML.  The problem is, myList always comes up empty, and I don't understand why.  I'm guessing that ExplorerViewContext.networkControllers in the original code is calling the getNetwrokControllers() method on an instance of ExplorerViewContext, yes?  Why can't I do the same thing in a scriptlet and reformat the output a little before serving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add scriptlet code to code that is already using JSTL only. The better thing to do would be to edit the bean class `src.explorer.ExplorerViewContext` to sort the insides for you automatically.

In any case, the reason `${myList}` does nothing in the JSTL is that variables created in scriptlets (i.e. between `<%` and `%>`) do not exist for JSTL. To get a variable to exist in JSTL you have to create it in JSTL, or set it in the page context, or it has to be in the session or the request. Generally you put it in the session or request in a servlet.

In this case, your list is in the bean, so it would be better to just edit the bean class to sort the list. But you could set the variable into the page context here so that JSTL can use it:

```
<%
...
List myList = ExplorerViewContext.getNetworkControllers();
java.util.Collections.sort(myList,NC_ORDER);
pageContext.setAttribute("myList", myList); //set in pageContext so JSTL can see it
%>
<c:forEach var="nc" items="${myList}">
```

As far as the code being "legacy" adding scriptlets to it would make it even more legacy.  The fact is, this code is more modern than the modifications you were trying to add. But only slightly so, since using `<jsp:useBean>` is an obsolete way of using beans.

Comment: Thank you very much for the good answer.  Without a doubt, editing the bean would be ideal.  However, I only have .class files for the beans, and I don't know if decompiling that one to make modifications is the best way to go.  I'm sorry, I should have clarified that.

Comment: @Frank, Well, if you don't have the code you have to do what you have to do. The fact is, I'm not as adverse to scriplets as most people on here are. I could see a case for using them a little if its done without being messy.